# Is there any way to send sms to a mobile number using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, mobile, messaging, telephony, sms

I want to send sSMS periodically to certain Mobile numbers (Indian mobile numbers.) Is there a way I can send an SMS with my own cellphone number or by creating an account on a site like `way2sms`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about finding an external service, not about U&L

Comment: A shell script can do anything you want -- or can -- so either an email or a curl call, but beyond that is outside this site's scope.

Answer (score 5):

This question hasn't much to do with Linux, but many providers also allow you to send a SMS to a mobile number via email, e.g. to send a SMS to 555-1234 you would send an email message to 5551234@smsgateway.provider.com or similar.  In this case on Linux you can achieve what you want via the command

```
mail 5551234@smsgateway.provider.com < sms.txt
```

Comment: I'm glad your answer was added before the question was closed.  It was my impression that this Unix & Linux site included using the shell scripting functions for normal computer tasks.  The function, in this case, is the "mail" command which you provided.  Hope the powers-that-be will reopen the question so that this resolution can remain easy to find.  I'm upvoting this invaluable command you provided.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you need an SMS Gateway account. Specific details on using the gateway are available on the providers sites.

Here's an example:

```
curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number=5551551555 -d "message=hello from OSXDaily.com"
```

http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/12/send-sms-text-message-from-command-line/

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you could verify that this method worked in India, and also specified a workable provider for this service. I'm also in India, and am somewhat interested in such a service.

Comment: @FaheemMitha ehm, I am not so sure. The OP is not responsible for checking if the method works everywhere.

Comment: Everywhere? The question specifies India.